# How to extract record from 10 to 20

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query :

```
IEnumerable<Pack> pack = from Pack myPack in Packs
                         select myPack;
```

that return (for example) 34 records. I need to select only records from 10 to 20. How can I do it?

Comment: If you are querying a database using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework then you will more than likely want to do your Skip/Take operations on IQueryable<Pack> instead of IEnumerable<Pack>. That way it will do the paging in the database instead of retrieving all records and then skipping/taking them on the client. Just make sure to do an OrderBy first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a combination of `Skip()` and `Take()`:

```
pack.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Or, if you want a single statement:

```
// if you want records 11 - 20 which would be the second set of 10
var packs = Packs.Skip(10).Take(10);

// or if you want records 10 - 20 which would be a set of 11
var packs = Packs.Skip(9).Take(11);
```

Comment: Technically that takes 11-20. I'm assuming he wants the second set of 10 and this answer is correct if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following? The idea is to project the row number onto each record. That way you can use it in the `where` clause.

```
var pack = 
  from x in Packs.Select((item, index) => new { RowNum = index + 1, Item = item }) 
  where x.RowNum >= 10 && x.RowNum <= 20 
  select x.Item;
```